# I am trying to copy code to design an antenna and it won't get past importing the first library

Tags: python-3.x

I am copying code from  the YouTube channel "Electric Technic" to create a WIFI antenna. The first line of code is import necpp, and it returns

```
usage: Antenna_Program.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

   or: Antenna_Program.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

   or: Antenna_Program.py --help-commands

   or: Antenna_Program.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

and it doesn't make it to the second line. I am running it on python 3.8. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Collecting necpp
Using cached necpp-1.7.3.5.tar.gz (196 kB)

Using legacy 'setup.py install' for necpp, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

Installing collected packages: necpp

```
Running setup.py install for necpp ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 command:
```

'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja8gohyf\necpp_814586d85464442390c86ab1614227f6\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja8gohyf\necpp_814586d85464442390c86ab1614227f6\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2as4gjdp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers

'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\necpp'
cwd: C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja8gohyf\necpp_814586d85464442390c86ab1614227f6\

```
Complete output (19 lines):

C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:717: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead

  warnings.warn(
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
copying necpp.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
running egg_info
writing necpp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to necpp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to necpp.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'necpp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENCE.txt'
writing manifest file 'necpp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building '_necpp' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja8gohyf\necpp_814586d85464442390c86ab1614227f6\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ja8gohyf\necpp_814586d85464442390c86ab1614227f6\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2as4gjdp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\necpp' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: What code are you running?

Comment: seeing that code in yt video and reading your issue, sounds like you havent installed the python package `necpp` yet, for that install it by doing `pip3 install necpp` in your cmd/shell. Posting the code and full error message will help people help you.